# window.location redirect to the home page in IE11 & mozilla

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla2.5

I am facing strange issue with IE11 & Mozilla that I have used window.location or document.location.href and window.location.href to redirect to particular link , And it's is working fine on all the browser and **IE version 7,8,9,10** but not working on **IE11** and mozilla latest version , I have searched a lot for it but couldn't find any solution yet. Here's my code what have tried :

```
<?php 
    $conc_getval2 =  JURI::root()."index.php?option=com_reconciliation&view=reconciliation&Itemid=135".$conc_getval;
?>
<a href="#" name="Client" title="Client" onclick="sortsection('getorderClient'); ">
  <?php echo JText::_('Client'); ?>
  <?php if(isset($getorderClient) && $getorderClient !=""){ ?>
    <img border="0" width="20" id="ascdec_img" name="ascdec_img" alt="<?php echo $alttagClient; ?>" title="<?php echo $alttagClient; ?>" align="absmiddle" src="<?php echo $imgClient; ?>"  />
  <?php } ?>
</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sortsection(gettype){
    var geturl = "<?php echo $conc_getval2; ?>";

    switch(gettype) {
    //alert(gettype);
    case 'getorderClient':
        var getorder = "<?php echo $_GET['getorderClient']; ?>";
        if(getorder == ""){
            var getorder = 'DESC';
            var mod_url = geturl+"&getorderClient=DESC";
        } else {
            if(getorder == "DESC"){
                var mod_url = document.URL.replace("DESC", "ASC");
            } else {
                var mod_url = document.URL.replace("ASC", "DESC");
            }
        }
        window.event.returnValue = false;   
        window.location = mod_url;
        //document.location.href = mod_url;
        break;
    }
}
</script>
```

Please help me resolve this.Thanks.

Comment: can you console.log the mod_url? if you go to that link will it work? There are maybe some mistakes when you don't actually write the full path to the window.location

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης I have tried it and in IE11 console it is working fine when i try to run it. But not within the above function..don't understand what is the problem. If you can help me to figure it out would be good for me.

Comment: i've searched the problem and I found out that incomplete urls don't work on IE11 for redirect, like you are missing the full path or something. So I wrote above to debug the redirect url, can't help you more

Comment: @ΘεόφιλοςΜουρατίδης what do you mean by incomplete url as you can see I am using joomla standard function to get the base uel and then add relative parameters to url and pass it to javascript, and it's working o rest of the browser and even in other ie versions.

Comment: have you tried setting window.location.href instead of window.location?

Comment: @Mallard Yes, But it's having same problem.

Comment: @Toretto can you share what is your generated `mod_url`? Just ensure it has `http` or `https` appended to it and then try again.

Comment: @srvikram13 Just for security concerned i can not shared the url but for your information, it has http:// in it.

Comment: @Toretto ok 2 last shots :) Can you try these 2 solutions? 1. changing `window.location.href = mod_url;`. and 2. `setTimeout( function(){window.location.href = mod_url;}, 0 );`

Comment: @srvikram13 Thank you for you suggestion, But I already tried, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

`window.event` doesn't exist in firefox, so this produce a js error.